# Is it insecure to just validate with SimpleSchema, and not use allow/deny rules?

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I am using SimpleSchema (the `node-simpl-schema` package) in an isomorphic way. Validation messages show up on the client as well as from `meteor shell`.

My question is whether or not this set up is actually secure, and if I need to also write allow/deny rules.

For example:

```
SimpleSchema.setDefaultMessages
  messages:
    en: 
      "missing_user": "cant create a message with no author"

MessagesSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    label: "Message",
    max: 200,
  },
  author_id: {
    type: String,
    autoform:
      defaultValue: ->
        Meteor.userId() 
    custom: ->
      if !Meteor.users.findOne(_id: @obj.author_id)
        "missing_user"
  },
  room_id: {
    type: String,
  }
}, {tracker: Tracker})
```

In `meteor shell` I test it out and it works as intended.

```
> Messages.insert({content: "foo", author_id: "asd"})
/home/max/Desktop/project/meteor/two/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/aldeed_collection2-core.js:501
      throw error;                                                                                                    // 440
      ^
Error: cant create a message with no author
```

Should I duplicate this validation logic in my allow/deny rules? Or can I let my `allow` function always return `true`, like I'm doing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some very simple rules that ensures the application is secure:

1. Do not use allow/deny rules - deny all client-side write requests.
2. If the client needs to write something in the database, they must do so through Meteor methods.
3. Ideally, the Meteor methods would call a function (which can be shared code, or server-specific code), and then check for the validity of the database modifier (using the Schema) would be done inside these functions.
4. Optionally, you can also create client-side methods, which would clean the object and carry out its own validation using the schema before calling the server-side method.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Currently I have this minimal allow function:

Comment: Messages.allow
  insert: (userId, message, fields, modifier) ->
    try
      MessagesSchema.validate(message)
      true
    catch e then false

Comment: I understand that it may be good from a design pattern perspective to use methods instead of allow/deny. But If I can just use SimpleSchema, then strictly speaking neither methods nor allow/deny is necessary. I would like to know if this is actually the case, or if `SimpleSchema` rules on the server can be overridden somehow.

Comment: Just to clarify, SimpleSchema does not actually impose any validation on the collection. For that, you'll need to use the [`collection2-core`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2-core) package and [attach](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2-core#attaching-a-schema-to-a-collection) the schema to the collection. (which it appears you are doing already). In that case, you don't need to attach additional allow/deny rules.

Comment: However, I strongly advise against this because 1. Methods are part of the core of Meteor, collection2 is not, if Eric decides to not support this package anymore, then you're stuck. 2. You have more flexibility defining rules inside functions than inside `autoValue`. I'd use the schema to check for whether the data has the right structure, but for security features like checking the user has the correct permission, I'd abstract that into a separate function and use a method to call it.

Comment: @d4nyll I think you should stretch out your last comment into your answer: allow/deny is for _authorization / permission_ (and give lot of power to the client), whereas Simple Schema is for data formatting / structure. These are 2 totally different objectives.